# Norm of bounded real function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X=[0,1]$ and $f$ be a continuous real function defined on $X$. The  norm of $f$ is defined by $\Vert f\Vert$=sup$\vert f(x)\vert$ Pls. how do i show that the function $f$ is bounded and for $g$ defined on $X$ prove $\Vert f+g\Vert\leq\Vert f\Vert+\Vert g\Vert?$

Comment: Neither is any function $f$ on a set $X$ bounded nor does the equality $\|f+g\| = \|f\|+\|g\|$ hold.

Comment: @saz Please, Why neither?

Comment: 1. Take $f(x) := x$ on $X=\mathbb{R}$. $f$ is not bounded. 2. Take $f=1$, $g=-1$, then $\|f+g\|=0$ whereas $\|f\|+\|g\|=2$.

Comment: I'm guessing there's more to the question than what you told us.  Perhaps a specific $f$ and $g$?

Comment: Yes, the question have been edited.

Answer (score 0):

To see that $f$ is bounded let $U_n := \{x \in [0,1] : |f(x)| < n\}$. Then $[0,1] \subset \bigcup_n U_n$. Since $[0,1]$ is compact we have $[0,1] \subset U_N$ for some $N$ and hence $x \in [0,1] \Rightarrow x \in U_N \Rightarrow |f(x)| < N$. I.e. $f$ is bounded by $N$. For the second part remark that if $f,g$ are continuous functions on $[0,1]$ then $|f(x)+g(x)| \leq |f(x)| + |g(x)|$ for all $x$.